# There's an extra separator in the navigation bar in SO?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Why there are 2 separators between **tools** and **chat**?

[image]

the view-source shows:

```
                  <span id="hlinks-nav">
                  <a href="/users/logout">log out</a>
 <span class="lsep">|</span>
<a href="/tools/">tools</a>
 <span class="lsep">|</span>

 <span class="lsep">|</span>

                  </span>
```

(Can't see it in other sites, but that's probably I don't have enough rep elsewhere :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for [pending edits from low-rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work) waiting for approval. When there are edits to approve a number appears there and clicking this takes you to a page where you can see other users edits and choose to accept or reject them.

[image: Indicator in top bar for pending edits]

Comment: Couldn't the appearance of the extra separator be conditional?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Indeed, [this is a bug.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=488666#488666)