# There's an extra space in MSO's header today

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an extra separator in the navigation bar in SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77486/theres-an-extra-separator-in-the-navigation-bar-in-so)

There's an extra space in the top header bar of MSO today. A thousand words:

[image: log out | tools | | chat | main | faq]

Comment: the same is on SO and only if you could see the suggested edits count.

Comment: I'm not seeing it. Then again, I don't have access to "tools". Could it be a space for the proposed edits?

Comment: Ah, I thought it was only MSO because I only have 10k here.